# Search values in php array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array like this:

```
array(5) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["go-out"]=> string(7) "#0d4b77" } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["cycling"]=> string(7) "#1472b7" } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["diving"]=> string(7) "#1e73be" } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["exploring"]=> string(7) "#062338" } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["eating"]=> string(7) "#f79e1b" } 
}
```

Let's say I have the first value like 'cycling', so how can I find the '#147217' value?

I have been trying a lot of combinations of

```
foreach ( $array as $key => list($key1 ,$val)) {
           if ($key1 === $id) {
               return $val;
           }
       }
```

But no luck.
Ideas?

Comment: have you tried array_search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column` -

```
array_column($your_array, 'cycling');
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/407856)

You should also add the checks for key's existence.

Answer (score 0):

you may still make one loop

```
$id =  "cycling";   
foreach($array as $val)
   if(isset($val[$id])) echo $val[$id];
```

[**Demo on Evail.in**](https://eval.in/407867)

Answer (score 0):

I have reformated tour code, try this, that works:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array("go-out" => "#0d4b77"),
    1 => array("cycling" => "#1472b7"),
    2 => array("diving" => "#1e73be"),
    3 => array("exploring" => "#062338"),
    4 => array("eating" => "#f79e1b")
);

$id = "cycling";

foreach ($array as $key => $entry) {
    if ($entry[$id]) {
        echo $entry[$id];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    0 => array("go-out" => "#0d4b77"),
    1 => array("cycling" => "#1472b7"),
    2 => array("diving" => "#1e73be"),
    3 => array("exploring" => "#062338"),
    4 => array("eating" => "#f79e1b")
);

$search = "cycling";

foreach ($array as $key => $entry)
    if (isset($entry[$search]))
        echo $entry[$search];
```

That works.

Nice day.